# Gunicorn can't find app when name changed from "application"

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I use `gunicorn --workers 3 wsgi` to run my Flask app.  If I change the variable `application` to `myapp`, Gunicorn gives the error `AppImportError: Failed to find application: 'wsgi'`.  Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

`myproject.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

myapp = Flask(__name__)

@myapp.route("/")
def hello():
    return 'Test!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myapp.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

`wsgi.py`:

```
from myproject import myapp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myapp.run()
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Gunicorn (and most WSGI servers) defaults to looking for the callable named `application` in whatever module you point it at. Adding an alias `from myproject import myapp as application` or `application = myapp` will let Gunicorn discover the callable again.

However, the `wsgi.py` file or the alias aren't needed, Gunicorn can be pointed directly at the real module and callable.

```
gunicorn myproject:myapp --workers 16
# equivalent to "from myproject import myapp as application"
```

Gunicorn can also call an app factory, optionally with arguments, to get the application object. (This briefly did not work in Gunicorn 20, but was [added back](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/pull/2178) in 20.0.1.)

```
gunicorn 'myproject.app:create_app("production")' --workers 16
# equivalent to:
# from myproject.app import create_app
# application = create_app("production")
```

---

For WSGI servers that don't support calling a factory, or for other more complicated imports, a `wsgi.py` file is needed to do the setup.

```py
from myproject.app import create_app
app = create_app("production")
```

```
gunicorn wsgi:app --workers 16
```

Answer (score 23):

If you're trying to serve an app with variable name `app` within `server/cats.py`, you can start the server on port 8000 as follows:

```
gunicorn server.cats:app -b 0.0.0.0:8000
```