# failed to find application 'wsgi' when launching upstart script

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, upstart

I'm trying to deploy a web app written using Flask onto an Ubuntu based VPS (hosted on Digital Ocean). I've run into an issue in the final steps of deployment.

Following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) I've gotten through everything up to the Upstart script where the project fails completely.

Looking in the log file after I `sudo start myproject` I found one line that reads: `Failed to find application 'wsgi'`

Folder Structure:

```
myproject
- venv
- templates
- static
- wsgi.py
- main.py
```

The wsgi.py is:

```
from main import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Finally, the Upstart file is currently:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid myuseraccount
setgid www-data

env PATH=/var/www/myproject/venv/bin
chdir /var/www/myproject

exec gunicorn --workers 2 --bind unix:myproject.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
```

I've sent a lot of time trying to troubleshoot,but I am lost. Everything works properly when I start the project using `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi:app` inside of the virtual environment.

Just in-case it is relevant, the nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myproject.com www.myproject.com;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I've just had the same issue. There's another question's answer that should help you with this as it did help me: [Gunicorn can't find app when name changed from "application"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379287/gunicorn-cant-find-app-when-name-changed-from-application)