# Gunicorn: Failed to find attribute 'app' in 'wsgi' when attempting to start flask server

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

Gunicorn fails to start flask server with the error: `Failed to find attribute 'app' in 'wsgi'.`.

The wsgi.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/root/customer-account-automation/")

from app import app as application
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

app.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
...
```

Project structure:

```
(customer-account-automation) root@jsd-user-management:~/customer-account-automation# tree
.
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── README.md
├── __pycache__
│   ├── app.cpython-37.pyc
│   └── wsgi.cpython-37.pyc
├── app.py
├── customerAccountMgmt.py
├── get-pip.py
├── static
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── bulma.min.css
│   ├── highlight.min.css
│   ├── highlight.min.js
│   └── styles.css
├── templates
│   ├── 404.html
│   ├── base.html
│   ├── change_password.html
│   ├── create_user.html
│   ├── deactivate_user.html
│   └── login.html
└── wsgi.py
```

I checked ([Gunicorn can't find app when name changed from "application"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379287/gunicorn-cant-find-app-when-name-changed-from-application/33379650)) but it doesn't relate to mine as I already use the `application`.

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: What is your shell command to run gunicorn? It's important so as to debug your error. For my case it is the param `gunicorn your.wsgi:yourappname` where you put :yourappname to be the app instance you create in your code

Comment: Your gunicorn command to run should be `gunicorn wsgi:app` instead of `gunicorn wsgi` I guess - the later one will use default instance name as application

Answer (score 22):

Gunicorn is looking for app in wsgi so change

```
from app import app as application
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

to

```
from app import app as application
app = application
```

Then you can run do...which is what i am guessing you are doing

```
gunicorn <all the options here> wsgi:app
```

Answer (score 3):

Start gunicorn like this:

```
gunicorn app:app
```

The `:app` tells gunicorn to look for the app variable within `app.py`